# Javascript if/else not working as expected

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to toggle a hidden menu with a link. But **when i click on the link, it reopens the hidden menu instead of closing it**.

**Here is how i expect it to run:**

- When i click `labelLink`
    if `hiddenBox` 's `display = 'none'`, then change it to `display = 'block'`
    if `hiddenBox` 's `display = 'block'`, then delete its focus by `blur()` and set it `display='none'`
- When i click outside of the `hiddenBox` when it has the focus, set hiddenBox 's `display='none'`
  (*This part is working well.*)

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/m0nct0rd/)

```
<ul>
    <li> 
        <a id="labelLink"  href="#" 
            onclick="
                if(document.getElementById('hiddenBox').style.display === 'block'){
                    document.getElementById('labelLink').focus();
                    document.getElementById('hiddenBox').style.display ='none';
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById('hiddenBox').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('hiddenBox').focus();
                }
                return false;"
        >
        Click Me
        </a>
        <div id="hiddenBox" tabindex="-1"  
            onblur="document.getElementById('hiddenBox').style.display ='none';"
        >
        I was hidden
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The `onblur` is firing before `onclick` when you click out of it, so it hides.  The `onclick` handler than shows it again immediately.  You'll need to redesign this bit of logic

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way instead.

```js
var labelLink = document.getElementById('labelLink');
var hiddenBox = document.getElementById('hiddenBox');

labelLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hiddenBox.style.display = hiddenBox.style.display == 'block' ? 'none': 'block';
});

labelLink.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  hiddenBox.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
#hiddenBox {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a id="labelLink" href="#">Click Me</a>
    <div id="hiddenBox" tabindex="-1">I was hidden</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that the OP was setting focus on the `hiddenBox` element, so this isn't quite the same behaviour.  If it's want the OP wanted though, that's fine!

Comment: @JamesThorpe - There is no need to set focus on `hiddenBox`.

Comment: No - probably isn't, just wanted to highlight that the behaviour is a bit different in case people miss it - I saw what you posted was working and wondered why :)

Comment: It is ok, I just used focus to be able to use onblur method to hide it when clicked outside of the box.

Comment: With your code hiddenBox doesn't get  closed when clicked outside of it.

Comment: @SalihErikci - Now it does.

Comment: In this version clicking on the hidden box also hides the hidden box.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, the two event listeners are interfering with each other. One way of fixing this is to remove the listener on `labelLink` when the hidden box is shown, and restore the listener with a slight pause after the hidden box is hidden again. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/894pooz9/)

```js
var labelLink = document.getElementById('labelLink'),
    hiddenBox = document.getElementById('hiddenBox');    
labelLink.addEventListener('click', showBox);
hiddenBox.addEventListener('blur', hideBox);
function showBox(){
    hiddenBox.style.display = 'block';
    hiddenBox.focus();
    labelLink.removeEventListener('click', showBox);
}
function hideBox() {
    hiddenBox.style.display = 'none';
    labelLink.focus();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        labelLink.addEventListener('click', showBox);
    }, 500);
}
```

```html
<a id="labelLink"  href="#" >Click Me</a>
<div id="hiddenBox" tabindex="-1" style="display:none" >I was hidden</div>
```